# A suitable JVM could not be found while installing apache UIMA

Tags: java, jvm, uima

I am trying to configure apache UIMA following - [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/downloads/uima/requirements.html)

I tried with 1.4.5 and 1.4.4 both downloader from - [link](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/download.do?source=uimasdk&S_PKG=dl&S_TACT=105AGX11&S_CMP=LPDB2&lang=en_US&cp=UTF-8)

But when I try to execute bin file, it gives :

```
Searching for Java(tm) Virtual Machine...
.................................A suitable JVM could not be found. Please run the program again using the option -is:javahome <JAVA HOME DIR>
```

I have already installed jdk6,7

```
root@kishor-desktop:/tmp# sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
```

I tried with both, but still no help.

Environment variables are already set:

```
root@kishor-desktop:/tmp# $JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386: Is a directory
```

I am using ubuntu OS.

**UPDATE 1 :**

```
root@kishor-desktop:/tmp# update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386
java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386 1051 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386
```

Comment: You appear to have three JRE(s) installed; have you tried installing a JDK?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: it is already installed. There's two JRE, but it display in this way I guess. Auto jre with `0`

Comment: What does `update-java-alternatives -l` show?

Comment: At the provided link I see *Operating systems: Windows® 2000, Windows XP, and Linux® Intel® 32-bit platforms (tested)* and *Java tool: Java 1.4 (tested with IBM Java SDK 1.4.2 (included in installer package); will not run on 1.3 or lower levels)*. **Ouch**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: yeah, that's fine na. We have version  > 1.4

Comment: Glad it's working then! Obviously 2000 was ~15 years now, and none of those are supported anymore.

Comment: but on linux it should work

Comment: It should work on Linux or Windows, but you'll apparently need a 32-bit JDK (possibly on a 32-bit OS) in the 1.4 series. Maybe it would work with 1.5; possibly it must be IBM's. As I said, *ouch*.

Comment: Can you make sure there is no problem with the installation ? What do you get when asking for the version: $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version

Comment: UIMA 1.x is *ancient*. IBM has donated UIMA to Apache ages ago. Why not use the current Apache UIMA (http://uima.apache.org)?

Comment: @rec: thanks for suggstion, does apache UIMA has all functionality that ibm UIMA has?

Comment: In general yes and more. A few concepts have been superseded by others. You can find a migration guide here: http://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.6.0/overview_and_setup.html#ugr.project_overview_changes_from_previous

Comment: @rec: thanks, I am trying to configure uima for last few days. no luck still. Have you ever tried it?

Comment: @puncrazy: Actually, I'm a member of the Apache UIMA project, so yes :) Maybe this tutorial from GSCL 2013 can help you get your feet on the ground: https://code.google.com/p/dkpro-tutorials/wiki/GSCL2013

Comment: Mind that I use UIMA, I didn't try migrating from IBM UIMA 1.x to Apache UIMA 2.x. I started using UIMA only after it had been migrated to Apache.

Comment: @rec: thanks for this information :). Does NLP support like lexical answer type detection, focus word detection are there in UIMA only? i thought it would be in ibm uima only

Comment: The core UIMA framework enables unstructured information analysis pipelines, but it does not provide any analysis per-se. There are various collections of UIMA components, e.g. DKPro Core or ClearTK (cf http://markmail.org/message/5ie4mti3thqrvhou). Stackoverflow is probably not a good place to continue this conversation. Please consider switching to the uima-user mailing list (http://uima.apache.org/mail-lists.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67217/discussion-between-puncrazy-and-rec).